# Nexus 5 Lollipop goes into Recovery while trying to update to 5.0.1

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, android-versions

I'm using LG Nexus 5 Lollipop (manually installed 5.0) and rooted with TWRP.

I just go notification to update to **5.0.1**. But when download and install, the phone automatically goes into TWRP Recovery mode, and if I restart from there nothing happens. I have to download the update again and so on...

Manual adb sideload doesn't work because of TWRP recovery.
Also I have tried sideload from inside TWRP, doesn't work.

Basically if I try adb sideload, on fastboot screen it get error: no device found. (Please note: if I use adb command while connected to PC in normal phone state adb commands work fine. even the adb reboot bootloader.)

Updated: after following below answer, if you too get stuck like me while on adb sideload, please update your drivers like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXtbAMarHQw

If you face error: closed while adb sideload
then type this command: `adb usb`
and then type `adb sideload UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.40.zip`

Comment: Probably, you can try sideloading the update instead of taking the OTA.

Comment: ok will try to update manually

Comment: Update: Manual adb sideload doesnt work. cus of TWRP recovery. also I have tried sideload from inside TWRP, doesnt work. basically if I try adb sideload, on fastboot screen it get error: no device found. (Please note: if I use adb command while connected to PC in normal phone state adb commands work fine. even the adb reboot bootloader.)

Comment: @STEEL Please do it again, cause the `fastboot` & `adb` driver needs to get installed again, when you select
`apply update from ADB`. TWRP is flashed after you sideload the update.

Comment: Ok, now im stuck at adb sideload UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.40.zip. Gives me error: closed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using this method:

https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/ec0a852428c19705380e

Give thanks to [this guy](https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup) of course.

**EDIT:**

*The steps outlined in this document assume the `Android SDK` to be installed on your PC and the `adb`, `fastboot` and `android.[bat|sh]` to be in your `PATH` variable!*

Download OTA zip from Google's servers to your PC.

http://goo.gl/dx2JoM - `signed-hammerhead-LRX22C-from-LRX21O.785a2f7a.zip`

Rename the downloaded zip to 'update.zip' (without the quotes (and if you're on windows and known file extension are hidden, make sure you not end up with update.zip.zip)).

To the same folder, download the latest SuperSU flashable zip.

http://goo.gl/XRK49m - `UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.40.zip`

To the same folder, download the latest TWRP recovery image for hammerhead.

http://goo.gl/XhAOt7 - `openrecovery-twrp-2.8.2.0-hammerhead.img`

To the same folder, 
download the 5.0 factory image tgz archive from Google's servers.
http://goo.gl/Z8ITiM - `hammerhead-lrx21o-factory-01315e08.tgz`

From the 5.0 tgz archive extract the

`recovery.img`

`boot.img` and

`system.img` files to the same directory where your downloads are located.
(Tip: With 7zip, for example, you can 'internally' open the archives within the archive and extract just the files you need. The same is possible with command line tools, of course.)

Update `platform-tools` and `tools` of the sdk manager.

Connect your device (USB debugging enabled, of course) to your PC.

Back at your terminal, go on by running the commands as follows (type only those lines prefixed with '> ', but without actually typing the '> '!).

```
# Make sure the device is recognized
> adb devices

# Boot into bootloader mode
> adb reboot bootloader

# In bootloader mode, make again sure the device is recognized
> fastboot devices

# Flash stock LRX21O recovery image
> fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

# Flash stock LRX21O system image
> fastboot flash system system.img

# Flash stock LRX21O boot image
> fastboot flash boot boot.img
```

When the last flash is confirmed, use the volume rockers to choose `'Recovery mode'` and confirm with the power button.

When you see the little Android lying with the red triangle warning sign on it, push power then volume up to get to the recovery options.

When you got to the recovery options, select '`apply update from ADB`' using the volume rockers again and press the power button to choose it. When the device says it's awaiting commands, type from the PC's command line:

```
adb sideload update.zip
```

When OTA update successfully installed, select '`reboot bootloader`' from the recovery options again using the volume rockers and press the power button.

Back in bootloader mode, type from the PC's command line:

```
fastboot flash recovery openrecovery-twrp-2.8.2.0-hammerhead.img
```

When the flash is confirmed, use the volume rockers to choose 'Recovery mode' and confirm with the power button.

Now in the TWRP recovery menu, choose `'Advanced' > 'adb sideload'`. Check both option, `clear 'Dalvik-Cache'` and `'Clear Cache'` and swipe the bar to start sideload mode. When the device says it's awaiting commands, type from the PC's command line:

```
adb sideload UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.40.zip
```

When done, confirm to reboot system. Finished. Mission completed.

You're now on 5.0.1 with your custom recovery, rooted and can pick up from where you left.

PS: First boot, as always, will take some minutes.

Comment: Take a look at now, I was just on a hurry, apologies.

Comment: TWRP is making it a trouble. I can do it manually either. On fastboot screen adb fails. No device found.

Comment: I cant do it manually that is what i ment.

Comment: `fastboot flash recovery openrecovery-twrp-2.8.2.0-hammerhead.img`

what you get after running this on the terminal?

Comment: I don't know why this is down-voted but this is the way to go!

Comment: @AndreaBaccega Thanks! I hope people follow the steps carefully cause it worked for me( just the updating binaries didn't work but it booted normally,with data intact. I flashed the updated binaries later manually). Previously: `LRX210,TWRP`.

Comment: Everyone who downvoted the answer should use an iPhone. ;) Kidding, but seriously.. This answer is correct. I know, since I wrote it. :P It is a sledge hammer method, but will work universally for everyone with a system that is set up correctly.

Comment: @IronBlossom this is the best writeup I've ever seen.  This is just what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: @eyecatchUp You are the man, MAN! :D

Comment: I did this now Im stuck in.. "Now send the package you want to apply screen" and from my PC when I type adb sideload update.zip.. same thing "NO DEVICE FOUND". Can i restart the phone directly, cus im stuck... CURRENTLY

Comment: where u said it takes 37 times pressing up valume + power. Dont do that. Instead while holding POWER BUTTON; Press VOLUME UP button 3 times

Comment: @STEEL Bummer!!

Comment: works perfect for updating 5.0.1 to 5.1, too. This is my "go to" method for me. +100 if I could...